# verify $dist(f=x,Y)=0,5$ for $Y=\{f: f\in C[0,1], \int_0^1 f=0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We had the following example in class: Let $X=\{f:f\in C[0,1], f(0)=0\}$ and $Y=\{f\in X: \int_0^1 f=0\}$.
Then $Y\subset X$ is closed and $dist(f=x,Y)=0.5$.

I want to verify the example. I can show Y is a subspace of X. So let $x_i$ be a sequence in $X$. Then $x_i\rightarrow x\in X$. We have to show $x\in Y$. We know $\int_0^1 x_i=0$ for all $i$. Therefore $\int_0^1 x=0$.

How do you get the distance property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $y\in Y$ then $$\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |y(t) -t| \geq \int_0^1 (t-y(t)) dt =0.5$$
but on the other hand  we can construct a sequence $y_n \in Y$ such that $$||y_n -\mbox{id} || \to 0.5 .$$

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the space $X$ is endowed with the norm $\|.\|_1$ defined by $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$.

First, for all $g\in Y,\|f-g\|_1=\int_0^1|t-g(t)|dt\geq |\int_0^1(t-g(t))dt|=1/2$.

Then, $dist(f,Y)\geq 1/2$.

Second, for $n\geq 1$, we define $f_n\in Y$ by
$$f_n(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
   x , & \hbox{if } x\in[0,1-1/n] \\
   \alpha_n x+\beta_n , & \hbox{else.}
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Thus $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1f_n=0$.

Then by construction $f\geq f_n$ and 
\begin{equation*}
   \|f-f_n\|_1=\int_{0}^1(x-f_n(x))dx=\int_{1-1/n}^1xdx-\int_{1-1/n}^1f_n(x)dx
\end{equation*}
So
$$\|f-f_n\|_1=\int_{1-1/n}^1xdx+\int_{0}^{1-1/n}xdx$$

By letting $n\to\infty$ we deduce that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f-f_n\|_1=1/2$.

It follows that $dist(f,Y)=1/2$.